# Is it safe to hold references to tbb::concurrent_unordered_map items?

Tags: c++, tbb

I ran into some existing code that I inherited that looks up and stores references of structs that are stored in a tbb::concurrent_unordered_map. I know if it was an iterator it would be safe but a reference to the actual object seems fishy.

The code constantly inserts new items into the tbb::concurrent_unordered_map. Can an insert not change the physical location of the items contained inside the tbb map which would make the stored references point to the wrong place as it would for an std::map?

The tbb documentation states:

> "Like std::list, insertion of new items does not invalidate any
>   iterators, nor change the order of items already in the map. Insertion
>   and traversal may be concurrent."

I know for an std::list the location would not change when inserting new items but because the concurrent_unordered_map documentation talks about the order only I am worried that that does not explicitly say that it can move location.

Below is some pseudo code that demonstrates the concept of the code I ran into.

```
struct MyStruct {
    int i;
    int j;
};

//some other thread will insert items into myMap
tbb::concurrent_unordered_map <int, MyStruct> myMap;

MyStruct& getMyStruct (int id)
{
    auto itr=myMap.find (id);
    if (itr!=myMap.end ()) return itr->second;

    static MyStruct dummy {1,2};
    return dummy;
}


class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass (int id)
            :m_myStruct {getMyStruct (id)}
    {

    }

    void DoSomething () {
        std::cout<<m_myStruct.i<<std::endl;
    }
protected:
    MyStruct& m_myStruct; //reference to an item held into a tbb::concurrent_unordered_map
};
```

This code has been running for over a year at a relatively high frequency which seems to suggest that it is safe but I would like to know for sure that it is safe to keep hold of a reference to an item contained in a tbb::concurrent_unordered_map.

Rewriting the code is a lot of work so I would prefer to not have to do it if it is ok to leave it as is.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried so much about going into gray area of not completely documented behavior, why don't you store and use iterators instead? One problem is its size though ([run it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/896f6bbf518b88be)):

```
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

int main() {
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, int> m;
    printf("Size of iterator: %lu\n", sizeof(m.begin()));
}
```

This is because besides the [pointer to the element](https://github.com/intel/tbb/blob/2019_U6/include/tbb/internal/_concurrent_unordered_impl.h#L101), iterator has the [pointer to the container](https://github.com/intel/tbb/blob/2019_U6/include/tbb/internal/_concurrent_unordered_impl.h#L136) it belongs to. There is no list of pointers or any other structure, which registers all the iterators users create, thus the container cannot update an interator to point to a different address (it would be especially tricky in a parallel program). Anyway, such a relocation would cause additional user visible calls to moving/copy constructors of key/value types and thus would be documented. There is no such a warning in the documentation and adding it would cause backward incompatible change, which gives you a sort of indirect guarantee that you can safely keep pointers to your items instead of using iterators.